# Import initial table data to a .mwb model file 

Tags: mysql, import, mysql-workbench

How can I import initial table data to a .mwb file? I know that there is an `inserts` tab for each table, but I would like to import around 200 records and I don't want to do this by hand.

Answer (score 5):

It is not possible with the modern version of MySQL Workbench. There is no way, essentially, to model data - you can only upload it to the server (not the model). The only way currently is to edit one by one which isn't practical. Even if you reverse engineer a table filed with data, the inserts table of the EER model will be blank. You'll note that right-clicking on the row of the inserts tab gives a number of greyed out options including "load from file". I suspect the team didn't have time to implement them or something. Anyway, there is a simple work around if you know phpMyAdmin, which seems to handle CSV files well, or MySQL Workbench, which I have not gotten to work at all with CSV files.

---

### Solution:

Draw your DB model in MySQL Workbench, structure only. Place all your data in associated CSV files - I use Excel and save as CSV - very easy. Once you have your data modeled in Excel and the structure modeled in Workbench, forward engineer the DB, then use some other tool or technique to upload your Excel modeled data.

Not the greatest solution, but bug them to provide data modeling and maybe we'll be lucky in the next version.

Answer (score 0):

Currently this seems not to be possible. I too was hoping to be able to Reverse engineer from the insert statements in a script file, but 1. it didn't work :P and 2. actually the documentation explicitly states that these will be ignored:

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-workbench/wb-data-modeling.html#wb-reverse-engineering

> 7.7.9.1. Reverse Engineering Using a Create Script
>
> Reverse engineering using a create script is done by using the File, Import, Reverse Engineer MySQL Create Script ... menu options. Doing this opens a file open dialog box with the default file type set to an SQL script file, a file with the extension sql.
>
> You can create a data definition (DDL) script by executing the mysqldump db_name --no-data > script_file.sql command. Using the --no-data option ensures that the script contains DDL statements only. **However, if you are working with a script that also contains DML statements you need not remove them; they will be ignored.**

It seems that the lesson is that we ought to handle such resources (that are too large to be manually inserted) through some other medium, such as a versioned sql file. :(